# phpseclib - Timing out

Tags: php, windows, cygwin, phpseclib

First of all I just want to tell you that I've searched for about 4 hours now without finding any solution, so I decided to ask here.

I am using Windows with Cygwin.

I send an SSH Command to the server telling it to download some game server files, and this porcess can take up to 20 minutes to complete, which now times out my php page.
I've tried with `header (Location: URL);` but it's still waiting for a response from the server and then times out.
So..
Are there some way I can force the client to another page and still let the rest of the code continiue.

Best Regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the latest git version of phpseclib. As of the [latest commit](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/commit/65193d9a25baa59bc34479322a694f2cf1f16180) you can now download files in chunks.

eg. `$sftp->get('filename.ext', false, 0, 1000)`. In this example, it'll download bytes 0-1000 from filename.ext and return a string with those bytes. If you do `$sftp->get('filename.ext', false, 1000, 1000)` it'll download bytes 1000-2000.